# How to eject disk in osx before booting?

Tags: macos, windows, bootcamp, install

I have tried to install windows using boot-camp-assistant on mac-min ( new version ).

After first installation process, I am getting "**Disk error - press any key to restart**"

Now, The problem that I am facing is I am not able to eject the disk.

- I am not able to boot osx
- I am not able to boot windows.

Please help.

Sugar.

Comment: Did you mean ejecting the CD/DVD?

Comment: Yes ! @HMage - I am not able to eject DVD.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Apple documentation](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1533), you can either use eject and F12 as mentioned before, or keep your mouse button pressed.

If you keep `option` pressed during boot, it should ask you from what disk you want to boot. That might be a better solution.

Are you sure this is the issue though?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to press the eject button while booting ?

Just after you press the power button, press and hold Eject.

Comment: I am using USB ordinary keyboard not apple's standard keyboard.

Comment: I tried to press ALT, I also tried F12. But none of them worked.

Comment: @sugar keeping the F12 key pressed didn't work?

Comment: @sugar you could try to go to an Apple Store, and ask them to plug an Apple keyboard just to eject the DVD.

Comment: Eject button worked for me